# Must declare scalar variable @DateEnd using SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has 2 date pickers on it that are associated with parameters @DateStart and @DateEnd.  This is with SSRS 2005.  When I preview the report, I get an error that mentions the @DateEnd parameter, although its set as a report parameter the same way as the other.  When I preview, I get prompted for @DateStart, but not @DateEnd.
What would cause this?

Comment: Stored procedure or SQL statement?  Usually this stems from a typo somewhere.  If you post the query, we should be able to locate it.

Comment: Its just a statement with a dataset.  I was thinking its a typo as well, but I started in SSMS and the query works fine (provided I declare the date variables at the top)

Comment: I think I just figured it out.  I had to add these parameters to the dataset as well as the report

Comment: Ah yes, and map them accordingly.